# Who can see Opportunity Object other than Admin profile in DEV ORG?

Tags: opportunity, profile

I was working on some workbook stuff as part of my Admin Certification preparation. I was able to see the Opportunity Object as an Admin profile and able to do all required activities on it.

But when I tried to login as a different user under Standard Platform Profile couldn't able to see Opportunity Tab anywhere for that user/profile. I have checked all settings of Tab, Object, profile (Standard Platform and couple of other profiles) to make this enable for this Standard Profile/user, but no luck.

Is there any special setting or restriction for Opportunity Objects in other profiles other than Administrator for DEV ORG. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=standard_profiles.htm&language=en) **Standard Platform User** profile "Can use custom Force.com AppExchange apps developed in your org or installed from AppExchange. In addition, can use core platform functionality such as accounts, contacts, reports, dashboards, and custom tabs." This is why Opportunity object is not available for this user.

Comment: Thnx u r correct. Its not available to Standard User profile.

Comment: As an additional note, "Partner Portal User Licenses" can see Opportunities. 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_partnerportal.htm&language=en_US